# Is this a bad idea?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

I've been working on this problem for two days now. I'm working on an iPhone app that, at the moment, has  "dual layer" view (see picture.)  The semi-transparent orange panel covering the left third of the screen was created by simply resizing the sub-view (in IB) to take up less than half the screen so that, when that view loads, the original view is still exposed on the right.  This would allow the left view to be a "menu view" allowing a user to select what he or she would like to appear in the main view window (which is actually a `UIWebView`...see screen shot.)

[----- Click Here For Screen Shot-----](http://lcdapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/webview2.png)

If I'm going to keep this setup (assuming it's not a structural sin), the left-view clearly needs a way to communicate with the main view.  Can I invoke methods in the main-wiew ".m" file (WebViewController.m) like `viewDidLoad` and others from the "ETG" button on the orange subview?  Or is this just a really bad idea?  And if this isn't a bad idea or a sin against iPhone structure, how would you implement it? I'll thank you in advance for any helpful thoughts or suggestions you might have.  Thanks!

Comment: Programmer rule of thumb: If you have to ask if something is a bad idea, it usually is. "Not always, but often."

Comment: Ok... but what about whether or not it's even _possible_ to invoke a method on a parent view from a sub view?  Yes? No?  And if so, how?

Comment: The problem here may be that I'm stuck in Visual Basic where it seems that you can basically call anything from anywhere. In the tutorial I mentioned above [link](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/42476/0/page/3) the authors demonstrates how to pass data from one view to another by setting the property of the second view with the 'DatePicker' output from the current view, but I guess that's very different from calling a method in another view. I guess my question now is: is this even possible in Objective C at all? ...thanks for helping! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're following the model-view-controller pattern, which you generally should, then your view should send messages to the controller or modify the model, not another view. Although it really depends on what you're doing. In your case you are using the panel as a control, so you should implement in a fashion that makes it independent of other views.

Usually the only time you have views directly manipulate other views is in layout, and that is normally in a top-down fashion.

Again, these are general rules and there are always exceptions.

Comment: Thank you for that.  I've been hearing about the model-view-controller pattern and probably should read some more and thought I'd just hear the thoughts of anyone here.  I like to learn bad style, experience the pain of that so that good style then makes much more sense. ;)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing doesn't seem insane, but they way you go about talking to the main view might need a little work.

It seems like what you want to do is have the overlay view have a delegate that it can send messages to.  Does that seem like it would work for you?

Comment: In very simply terms, I'd like the UIWebView to load a new and different web page when a button on the layover view is pressed.  If I could do just that, the rest would be sort of normal.  I've looked into 'singletons', etc., but in the end, can I reload a web view from another view?  If I can't do that, what are my other options?

Comment: Who owns the webView and who owns the layover view?  It would be a bad idea to let the layover view directly talk to the webView, but if it sent a message to the owner of the webView, then the owner of the webView can call -loadRequest: on the webView to have it load a page, that would probably be fine.  This seems very much like something that would be appropriate to give the layover view a delegate that it can tell when a button in it is pressed

Comment: I believe that the layover view is owned by the webview and the webview is owned by an appdelegate.  Obviously, I'm new at this and build this app partly off a nice tutorial here [link](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/42476/0/page/3) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Umm, is the web view the main view?

Either way, I'd do this:

One view controller that contains two main areas. One is your UIWebView, and another is your layover. If you do this in Interface Builder, put the Layover on top of the UIWebView.

All you have to do is animate it in and out based on certain input. A bad idea is to say "hide menu" and make the UIWebView take up all the space, so you can't get it back.

Then use use one view controller for both.

The recommended method of communicating between view controllers, if that's subviewed, is to create properties in the view controller that you can pass. Eg: the web view needs to tell the main view what site it's on. So put an NSString in your main controller as a property, then pass it the string on viewWillDisappear or whatever that name is.

(Or, use viewWillAppear on the top level and have it grab that property from the 2nd view).

Essentially it's just a branching tree, and you have to pass data up one node to reach the others.

You "can" use the application's delegate itself/(the application) and from anywhere, call [UIApplication sharedApplication].property (after creating a property), and use it as a global, but that's not considered reusable code. Since you're used to basic, it might work for you.

Finally, C++ globals do work, and there are many examples on the web for using globals in an iPhone program with externs. (even less recommended).

Now, it sounds like you need to read the Views Programming Guide, even though it has severe grammar issues in areas (they may have corrected the homonyms in the 3rd paragraph of the intro by now, but other areas are totally confusing because of that), to get an understanding of how views respond to input, and what happens when input is ignored and bubbles up the tree. (that's basically what it does, lol... but layers and views have intricacies and it's good to understand them and how they function together).

No, it's not a bad idea. But without understanding layers, view animation, and design maybe it is, until you do.

NazCode

Comment: Thank you for your comment. [part one of two]  The Webview here is not the mainview.  Your suggestion, however, may be the one to follow. I was attached to the idea of having two separate views partly because the top view (the orange "layover" view) transitioned onto the webview via a page-curl that I wanted to keep (See effect in photo here [link](http://lcdapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/webview3.png)  )  I'm partly just exploring the boundaries of xCode to see what the options are. I was going to use a property to pass data from one screen to another. [see part 2]

Comment: [part 2] I was unable, however, to call a method in one view from another view and was beginning to believe that, short of doing something really ugly, this approach to the code simply couldn't be done. Putting the layover on the same view as the webview (as you suggested) is probably a lot more sensible from a programming angle.  At this point, however, I had gotten to the point of simply just being curious as to how to trigger a view method from a separate view (or if it was even an option!) BTW, there was a "Show Menu" button on the UIWebView (lower left-hand corner) [see part 3]

Comment: [part 3] that would bring back the layover from being hidden if desired. Regarding properties, I'm clear that that can be done (of course.) My question, however, is how can a property trigger (or be used to trigger) a "ReloadView" event or something?  I'm not familiar with the [UIApplication sharedApplication].property you mentioned.  I'll have to check that out.  Thank you!

Comment: Right now, I'm creating types of subviews inside my superviews. Essentially, I'm giving my subclasses pointers to their creators. Bad practice, but the code's clean. You might need to read the setNeedsLayout and setNeedsDisplay functions. iOS has a lot of... bugs? for lack of better terms. I can move the frames but not the position. Or my table is only selected if I click on it twice after it moves...? Honestly, I've coded for a decade, and never ran into something this finicky before. Google "Global variables" and you'll see how to use UIApp. See you, glad it helped a bit

Comment: Ok, I just got delegation working using the tutorial from this search http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=delegation+and+protocol#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&pq=delegation%20and%20protocol&xhr=t&q=delegation+and+protocol+objective&cp=33&pf=p&sclient=psy&safe=off&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=delegation+and+protocol+objective&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.&fp=d184bc9da719dfe6 saing "The Basics"... for some reason it wasn't working before, probably b/c I needed to use a NIB instead of code it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do, one approach is to use notifications. This way none of the objects involved need to have references to one another. Before I learned this approach, I had several awkward cases where I seemed to be working much too hard just to get two objects to talk to one another.

In your case, your orange layer can post notifications and the controller for the UIWebView can listen for them.

So when you tap the button in the orange layer, do something like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"etgTapped" object:self];
```

And in controller that looks after the webview add something like this to your viewDidLoad method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(etgTapped:) name: @"etgTappe" object:nil];
```

And then create an etgTapped: (NSNotifaction*) notification method in that class.

Finally, in viewDidUnload de-register with the notification centre:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Comment: Matthew: That feedback is very much appreciated. I was looking and thinking about a way to do something like this, but had NO CLUE had to do it, so thank you for this feedback and many others may fin it useful too since, so far, no one else made this suggestion.  Thank you! :)